# Request Fullscreen From Another Route in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a project built with Vue.js I am currently using an npm package called vue-fullscreen to provide the user the option to fullscreen a specific div element. Internally this package uses the built Element.requestFullscreen Web API.

Everything works great when the code is confined to a single component. All I do is set my toggle method on the `@click` attribute of a button element and call the fullscreen API within the toggle method.

I also want to provide the user the option to launch that div in fullscreen mode from another route. For example, I have a table with several elements. Normally, they would click the element to go to this next route, and they can opt to enter the div into fullscreen mode there. I would like to take out this middle step and launch into fullscreen directly from the previous route.

I initially tried doing this by passing a "startFs" property to the new route, and passing that down to the component that requires it. In this component's `mounted` method I check to see if `this.startFs` is true and if so I attempt to invoke the fullscreen API call on the div and show the element as fullscreen.

This however causes the error `Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture` since the `mounted` method is not a user gesture (even though the chain of events that led me there was originally triggered by a user gesture).

Is there any way that I can somehow launch this div element in fullscreen from another route?